# h2 outerWidth in IE 7 is shorter than IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I have encountered a problem today when i imeplement a correction in our project.

What i found is that the outerWidth for h2 in IE 7 is shorter than in IE8 (FF, Chrome etc).

Here is my code:

```
var h2width = $('.test h2').outerWidth(true)
```

h2width is 135px in IE8 and 78px in IE7.

Do you have any ideas for that?

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

For prevent this problem, i have added the code for differenciate the browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) <= 7) {
var h2width = $('.test h2').outerWidth(true) + 57;
} else {
var h2width = $('.test h2').outerWidth(true);
}
```

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using? Is it the same for all browsers or are they using their default DOCTYPE? That would explain why IE7 behaves differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers render HTML differently so this isn´t that strange.
Use Firebug or other development tool to view the actual size of your `h2` tag. They are most likely different.

Also notice that your selector `$('.test h2')` returns a collection of matched elements.

Comment: Yes, but there exist only one h2 in my case

Comment: Still, the selector returns an array or elements so use `$('.test h2').first()` or `$('.test h2')[0]` to access the first matched element.